# Trouble downloading a file with box.com python SDK

Tags: python, api, box

I  would appreciate some help, It can't be this hard to just be able to download a file. I have the most basic script possible, just trying to download a zip file:

```
from boxsdk import JWTAuth, Client

config = JWTAuth.from_settings_file(r'C:\Users\me\Desktop\test\498722505_4bso76em_config.json')
client = Client(config)
file_id= "690891438414"
client.file(file_id).content()
```

This would give me a 404 file not found error. I then found a post saying you need to add the account that is trying to download the file as a collaborator. I found this by running `client.user().get()['login']` which gave me `AutomationUser_1385795_xbf5Gr4R2I@boxdevedition.com`.

Now when I run the above script, it just hangs forever on `client.file(file_id).content()`, no error messages. What else am I missing?